# How can I check in a array of objects if one of the objects contain just a part of a string?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

How can I check in a array of objects if one of the objects contain just a part of a string ?

```
products = [
{id: 'pdc', code: '123456', name: 'pompa'},
{id: 'kbr', code: '2365', name: 'kit kbr'},
{id: 'boiler', code: '23165', name: 'VPB'}
];
```

And let's say I want to find if the this.products contain an object with 'kbr' ? And, as you can see, that object has a longer name.. Something like:

```
const matches = this.products.filter(s => s.includes('kbr'));
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need the values of the object and then iterate until a match is found.

```js
var products = [{ id: 'pdc', code: '123456', name: 'pompa' }, { id: 'kbr', code: '2365', name: 'kit kbr' }, { id: 'boiler', code: '23165', name: 'VPB' }],
    matches = this.products.filter(o => 
        Object.values(o).some(v => v.toString().includes('kbr'))); 
 
console.log(matches);
```

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there. You simply needed to access the "name" property of your object "s". In this scenario I used [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to get quick access to "name" property.

```js
const products=[{id:"pdc",code:"123456",name:"pompa"},{id:"kbr",code:"2365",name:"kit kbr"},{id:"boiler",code:"23165",name:"VPB"}];

const res = products.filter(({name})=>name.includes("kbr"));

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

In the filter function, you didn't specified the field to be checked.
So you've to write this if you want to check on name property:

```
const matches = this.products.filter(s => s.name.includes('kbr'));
```

Comment: And if I don't know where to look ? Let's say I don't know if that value/part of string that I look about it is in the name propriety ..

Comment: Ops i forgot to write this: const matches = this.products.filter(s => Object.values(s).includes('kbr'));

Answer (score 1):

using `some` is a better approach for this, it will stop as soon as it founds something.
for larger arrays it will be an improvement :)

```js
products = [
{id: 'pdc', code: '123456', name: 'pompa'},
{id: 'kbr', code: '2365', name: 'kit kbr'},
{id: 'boiler', code: '23165', name: 'VPB'}
];

const result = products.some(product => Object.keys(product).some(key => product[key].includes('kbr')))
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could compose all values to a string and check if it includes that:

```
 const matches = this.products.filter(s => Object.values(s).join("¥").includes('kbr'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the array of the [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) inside the filter  method and check if some of the `values` [match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) the string you are searching for:

```js
const products = [
    {id: 'pdc', code: '123456', name: 'pompa'},
    {id: 'kbr', code: '2365', name: 'kit kbr'},
    {id: 'boiler', code: '23165', name: 'VPB'}
];

let res = products.filter(o =>
{
    return Object.values(o).some(x => ("" + x).match("kbr"));
});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can stringify the object values and see if it has the substring you're looking for :

```js
const products = [{ id: 'pdc', code: '123456', name: 'pompa' }, { id: 'kbr', code: '2365', name: 'kit kbr' }, { id: 'boiler', code: '23165', name: 'VPB' }];

const result = products.filter(prod =>
  Object.values(prod).join(' ').includes('kbr'));

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use Array.find() function, because it stops at the first matching object:

```js
const products = [
    {id: 'pdc', code: '123456', name: 'pompa'},
    {id: 'kbr', code: '2365', name: 'kit kbr'},
    {id: 'boiler', code: '23165', name: 'VPB'}
];

const testPattern = 'kbr';

const productsContains = (products, pattern) => 
    products.find(
      ({id, name}) => 
          id.indexOf(pattern) >= 0 || name.indexOf(pattern) >= 0
      ) ? true : false;

console.log(`productsContains '${testPattern}':`, productsContains(products, testPattern));
```

It isn't working in IE, but there is polyfill.